# Zoom Boxes With Content Inside On Hover

Tags: css, grid, hover

I have 4 boxes, each with a fontawesome icon, a background for the icon, an h3 and a p with some text. When I hover i want the box and everything inside to scale about 1.1. I've tried adding transition to the boxes class and and scale on hover but it does nothing. I also tried adding these properties to each element inside the box individually. Im using grid to align the boxes horizontally and vertically on mobile. Im not including the media queries.

The first orange box titled "box" is a very basic example of what i want to accomplish with the rest of the boxes.

this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42f1fd7b3c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./box.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="zoom-box">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            </div>
            <h3>box</h3>
            <p>box zooms on hover</p>
        </div>
        
        <section id="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <div class="service_grid">
                        
                <div class="service_box dlvry">
                    <div class="truck_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Delivery</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit fuga quasi molestias error aliquam sint alias cum, praesentium blanditiis amet placeat nemo soluta voluptate. Non ex provident distinctio voluptatem fuga.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box mnfct">
                    <div class="industry_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-industry fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Manufacture</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias dolor repellendus velit inventore. Nam rerum eligendi libero odit, vero accusantium est placeat provident id animi vitae quaerat dolore fugit unde?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box mktg">
                    <div class="bullhorn_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-bullhorn fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Marketing</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti doloribus velit cum molestiae eius accusantium, et debitis sapiente quae culpa, cupiditate eum magni quod quas nam dolorum, hic voluptatum accusamus!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box merch">
                    <div class="store_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-store fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Merchandising</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum obcaecati nostrum qui incidunt consequatur repellendus, commodi eligendi placeat voluptates! Iste magnam illum debitis modi fugiat aliquam vero unde, minima sequi?</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the css

```
/* GLOBALS */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* EXAMPLE BOX */
.zoom-box {
    background-color:#CF4B32;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 32px auto;
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}

.zoom-box h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.zoom-box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* EXAMPLE BOX END */


/* BOXES WITH NO HOVER EFFECT */
#services { 
    background: rgb(0, 0, 17);
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#services h1 {
    padding: 80px;
    color: #fdfffc;
    text-align: center;
}

.service_grid {
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 'de mn ma me';
}

.service_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:  #fdfffc;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.service_box h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

/* ICONS & BACKGROUNDS */ 

.icon_back {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
} 

.dlvry {
    grid-area: de;

}        

.truck_back {
    background: #b0def5;
    padding: 20px;
}   

.fa-truck {
    
    color: #03254c;

}

.mnfct {
    grid-area: mn;
}

.industry_back {
    background: #f1acac;
    padding: 20px;
}

.fa-industry {
    color: #b71c1c;
}

.mktg {
    grid-area: ma;
}

.bullhorn_back {
    background: #fcf088;
    padding: 20px;
}

.fa-bullhorn {
    color: #fabc20;
}

.merch {
    grid-area: me;
}

.store_back {
    padding: 17px;
    background: #aed581;
}

.fa-store {
    color: #33691e;
}
/* ICONS & BACKGROUNDS END */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same code for your example seems to work...

I added/edited this to your CSS:

```
.service_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:  #fdfffc;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: justify;
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}


.service_box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Working example:

```css
/* GLOBALS */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* EXAMPLE BOX */
.zoom-box {
    background-color:#CF4B32;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 32px auto;
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}

.zoom-box h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.zoom-box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* EXAMPLE BOX END */


/* BOXES WITH NO HOVER EFFECT */
#services { 
    background: rgb(0, 0, 17);
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#services h1 {
    padding: 80px;
    color: #fdfffc;
    text-align: center;
}

.service_grid {
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 'de mn ma me';
}

.service_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:  #fdfffc;
    border-radius: 5%;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: justify;
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}


.service_box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}


.service_box h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

/* ICONS & BACKGROUNDS */ 

.icon_back {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
} 

.dlvry {
    grid-area: de;

}        

.truck_back {
    background: #b0def5;
    padding: 20px;
}   

.fa-truck {
    
    color: #03254c;

}

.mnfct {
    grid-area: mn;
}

.industry_back {
    background: #f1acac;
    padding: 20px;
}

.fa-industry {
    color: #b71c1c;
}

.mktg {
    grid-area: ma;
}

.bullhorn_back {
    background: #fcf088;
    padding: 20px;
}

.fa-bullhorn {
    color: #fabc20;
}

.merch {
    grid-area: me;
}

.store_back {
    padding: 17px;
    background: #aed581;
}

.fa-store {
    color: #33691e;
}
/* ICONS & BACKGROUNDS END */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42f1fd7b3c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./box.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="zoom-box">
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
            </div>
            <h3>box</h3>
            <p>box zooms on hover</p>
        </div>
        
        <section id="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <div class="service_grid">
                        
                <div class="service_box dlvry">
                    <div class="truck_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-truck fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Delivery</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit fuga quasi molestias error aliquam sint alias cum, praesentium blanditiis amet placeat nemo soluta voluptate. Non ex provident distinctio voluptatem fuga.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box mnfct">
                    <div class="industry_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-industry fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Manufacture</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias dolor repellendus velit inventore. Nam rerum eligendi libero odit, vero accusantium est placeat provident id animi vitae quaerat dolore fugit unde?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box mktg">
                    <div class="bullhorn_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-bullhorn fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Marketing</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti doloribus velit cum molestiae eius accusantium, et debitis sapiente quae culpa, cupiditate eum magni quod quas nam dolorum, hic voluptatum accusamus!</p>
                </div>

                <div class="service_box merch">
                    <div class="store_back icon_back">
                        <i class="fas fa-store fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Merchandising</h3> <br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum obcaecati nostrum qui incidunt consequatur repellendus, commodi eligendi placeat voluptates! Iste magnam illum debitis modi fugiat aliquam vero unde, minima sequi?</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To scale on hover you should add css code below.

```
.service_box:hover{
transform: scale(1.1);
```

}

You can test your code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and add my hover code.